# Ubuntu fatal error was encountered. The library 'libhostpolicy.so' required

Tags: .net, dll, .net-core, ubuntu-16.04

I'm quite new to Ubuntu. I've been trying to run a dll via dotnet but each time I launch I get a "fatal error was encountered. The library 'libhostpolicy.so' required to execute the application was not found in '/root/duo/'.

I did a

```
 sudo updatedb && locate hostpolicy.so | xargs sha1sum
```

and got:

```
 1c51298979874c5ff0e30798406760c77bea7adc  /root/sdk/1.0.4/libhostpolicy.so
 a930b639bf61b038869d69aea1e773648f77a7c4  /root/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.5/libhostpolicy.so
 1c51298979874c5ff0e30798406760c77bea7adc  /root/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.1.2/libhostpolicy.so
 dd784807e436e626a7a223d8b8010c537f01b6a5  /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/1.0.4/libhostpolicy.so
 93c2979d35dd12c6eb516e742af3ccc5c9504438  /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.5/libhostpolicy.so
 dd784807e436e626a7a223d8b8010c537f01b6a5  /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.1.2/libhostpolicy.so
 28998aec4bb7bf1b592ba34de4ffb280249c073f  /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.0 <missing content>
```

What is going on and how do I get it resolved and point to the said directory. Do I have any conflicts, as I previously had a dotnet issue I had to resolve?

Comment: Did you work this out?

Comment: Nope not yet still stuck there.

Comment: Could you add the contents of `dotnet --info`. Run it after `cd`ing into the project directory.

Comment: What `dotnet` command was run? `dotnet the.dll` or `dotnet run` on a project? if so, the csproj contents would be interesting. Also note that there are newer SDKs now (1.1.5 and 2.1.2) that contain lots of bug fixes over the `1.0.*` versions.

Comment: Looks like the SO is unavailable in dotnet 2.0 but is available in dotnet 1.0.  Can you run your dll on an older version of dotnet?  Or upgrade to the latest version of dotnet 2.0?  Latest version at https://www.microsoft.com/net/

Comment: You can look at my answer about this question;
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65924378/2643226