# The library 'libhostpolicy.so' required to execute the application was not found

Tags: .net-core, .net-core-2.0

During running a dotnet console application I encountered this error. I ran it from a directory that had the .dll and .pdb file copied into it.

What is the cause of this error?

Answer (score 5):

Please check chmod of application folder. When I change folder access mode, problem was resolved. I know it is a little weird but sometimes it can be related to that :)

You have to determine them like that;

```
sudo chown -R yourusername:yourusername /var/www/
sudo setfacl -R -d -m u:yourusername:rwx,g:yourusername:rwx,o::r /var/www/
```

If you don't have setfacl command please install ACL package via this command;

```
sudo apt install acl
```

**If this doesn't work**, please use this command when publishing your project(in Package Manager Console of Visual Studio);

```
dotnet publish -c Release --self-contained --runtime linux-x64 -o out
```

And it will create "out" folder in your solution directory, you can copy its contain to server.

Answer (score 1):

the `deps.json` and `runtimeconfig.json` must also be copied into the directory that the .dll is invoked in. Without these files you will encounter this error.

If you're doing post-build copies, make sure to include these files.

Comment: I am trying to run [paket.exe](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/paket-and-dotnet-cli.html) restore on microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk-alpine - there is no project.json. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I receive this error when I had compiled the dll using the incorrect runtime.

Running a `linux-x64` binary on a `linux-arm64` system will show this error and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for this. I forgot I'm running from an m1 mac...

Answer (score -1):

If you are running a solution that has multiple projects, check to make sure the correct startup project is set.